# Where is the hard disk in the mid 2012 15" Macbook pro with retina

Tags: macbook-pro, hard-drive

I was following various guides for replacing the hard drive. However my mac does not seem to have the standard 2.5" SSD/SATA drive: see this screenshot:

[image]

The black rectangular sections are too small to be 'normal' 2.5hdd's as can be seen here when comparing to the SSD:

[image]

Does anyone know

- what *are* those rectangular black compartments
- how do I swap this (or another smaller?) SSD into the MBPro?

Comment: All the black compartments are the batteries.

Comment: OK thx I did not know that. Where is the hard drive?

Comment: Your MacBook Pro uses a flash memory module so you won't be able to fit a 2.5'' drive in. That is where it is positioned http://bit.ly/29BSSaA . And here you can see a guide on replacing it http://bit.ly/29VUATE .

Comment: @John Well that merits an awarded answer: so answer away please.

Comment: Love it. Four downvotes and no comments. It's lovely to be a low rep user on this forum.

Comment: I didn't downvote, @javadba, but I'll guess that was because you didn't show even a minimal amount of research to seek an answer to your question before you posted it. SE sites — very reasonably — expect users to do this. In your case, for example, https://www.ifixit.com would have shown you the part and its location with only a few mouse clicks.

Comment: The question mentions "followed several guides". The research was there.  You may have found a site that has the info - so you did a *better* googling job.

Comment: Well, yes: any fix-it guide for a 2012 MBP 15" Retina would show the SSD as a small circuit board, just as it is. Did you by chance find guides which said otherwise?

Comment: Not knowing at the time that there were not a standard hard disk even present complicated my understanding of query results. This is not an unreasonable fact to be surprised about IMO.  SOF is supposedly trying to be more friendly to newer users - as opposed to expecting folks to be well aware of material before asking any questions.  In *this* forum I often fit more cleanly into that novice category - and as mentioned end up feeling the pain of other newer users that may not formulate the best google queries - or correctly interpret the results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. All the black compartments are the Li- Ion Polymer batteries which power your MacBook Pro.
2. You won't be able to swap a 2.5'' drive in your Macbook because the Mid 2012 Retina models use a flash memory module.[image]
   [Here](https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/MacBook+Pro+15-Inch+Retina+Display+Mid+2012+SSD+Replacement/9706) you can see a guide to upgrading the SSD.

Comment: Thx for the answer. I'm not necessarily *thrilled* about the apparent cost (if even possible) to do the 512GB upgrade ..